# JQUERY code is not working for each value of array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I want to do enable and disable select option while click on check box
but it only work for single value not for each value of array.

If I used the id as array to get the values of select it doesn't work

Kindly update my code or provide me alternative way.I already try java script it also not working properly

```
 <script>

    var update_courier = function () {
        if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $('#courier').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#courier').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    };

    $(update_courier);
    $("#checkbox").change(update_courier);
    </script>
    <div class="conatiner">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3" style="margin-top: -35%;">
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('invoice/invoidlist');  ?>" method="POST">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <?php foreach($details as $detail):?>

            <tr>
            <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $detail['OrderId'];?>"  name="checkbox">

                <td>
                    <?= $detail['OrderId']?>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <?= $detail['CustomerName']?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?=$detail['Address']?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?=$detail['ZipCode']?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?=$detail['FinanicalStatus']?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?=$detail['Payment']?>
                    </td>
                <td>
                <select id="courier">
                <option>(choose one)</option>
        <option value='1'>Bluedart</option>
            <option value='2'>Delhivery</option>
            <option value='3'>DTDC</option>
            <option value='4'>IndiaPost</option>
    </select>

            </td>
                </tr>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" style="margin-left: 30%;">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You must have unique ids, your for loop prints (i guess) more elements with same id - use class instead. Fix it first, and then, if problem persists, edit question with updated code...

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.Can you just tell me a sample code.

Comment: SO isn't here to just "fix it" or provide you with a finished written code, do your own debugging and help yourself become a better developer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g3fp48vy/)** - Created static `table` in demo given here

Instead of `id` on `checkbox` use `class` as id should be `unique` in **`HTML DOM`** and then you can write a `click` event to `checkbox` and enable or disable `select` element corresponding to its `row` as below

```
$(".chkSelect").on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.courier').prop('disabled',$(this).is(":checked"))
});
```

> Here `.chkSelect` is class for `checkbox` and `.courier` is class for `select`

Your updated `php` for `table` would be as below:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
     <?php foreach($details as $detail):?>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="chkSelect" type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $detail['OrderId'];?>"  name="checkbox">
            <td>
                <?= $detail['OrderId']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $detail['CustomerName']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$detail['Address']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$detail['ZipCode']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$detail['FinanicalStatus']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$detail['Payment']?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="courier"> <!--Change this to class-->
                    <option>(choose one)</option>
                    <option value='1'>Bluedart</option>
                    <option value='2'>Delhivery</option>
                    <option value='3'>DTDC</option>
                    <option value='4'>IndiaPost</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree this answer. Since you are iterating through your results, you need to come up with classes or with unique ids. Classes in this case would work best.